# How do I add HTML elements to the DOM with Google Dart?

Tags: jquery, html, dart

I am trying to auto generate options in a dropdown menu in HTML 5. I am trying to use the add function to add HTML Elements. Basically I want to be able to do what the jquery .append() function does.

I wanted to add options in a `<select>`, like this:

```
<options value="test">Test Option</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
querySelector('options').append(new SelectElement()..value = 'test'..text='Test Option);
```

or

```dart
querySelector('options').append(new Element.html('<options value="test">Test Option</option>'));
```